# How to show same panel on every monitor in KDE 5?

Tags: linux, debian, kde, desktop-environments

I'm using KDE 5.4.3 shipped with Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid.

I want to show a same panel on every monitor, but I didn't find the option.

I have been using Ubuntu Unity desktop environment for a long time, and I find Unity can have same panel on every screen, it's really useful for reducing mouse cursor moving distance when launching applications from panel.